# Asp .net core Action selection based on regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want an action in my controller to be hit whenever the route matches below expresion -

> */${name}

it means anything can exist before /${name} for example
Home/123/456/$abc or Home/$abc or /$abc

> There is a separate action for Post and Get.

how can i write a route for this in asp.net core?

Comment: Have you tried [Attribute routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee how to use attributerouting for this kind of route?

Comment: This problem cannot be solved directly, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: The conventional routing in any MVC project be it .NET framework or .NET core is `http:9999//localhost/{controllerName}/{actionName}/{optionalIds}` however if you need to modify the conventional route and build your own custom route you include `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoute()` method in `RouteConfig.cs` file and use the `[RouteAttribute()]` on top of your action method which enables attribute routing. The MSDN article explains how to use it. But the thing which you are after is not solvable using Conventional Routing. Try using **Attribute Routing constraints**.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee i am aware of attribute routing but can i write a route like this [HttpGet,Route("*/${customOperation}")] ?

Comment: no you cannot use it, try thinking of a different approach.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee yes seeking help for that only.